# Loop through class. Get input and span values

Tags: jquery, loops, input, html-lists, html

Just when I think I am beating JQuery I get stumped.

```
<div class="productAttributeValue">
<div class="productOptionViewRectangle">
<ul>
    <li class="option">
        <label for="dca37e79338c28f796c3bdd4e88492f2">
            <input
                type="radio"
                class="validation"
                name="attribute[52]"
                value="97"
                id="dca37e79338c28f796c3bdd4e88492f2"
                        />
            <span class="name">25 ML</span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="option">
        <label for="b6cc5db62235218dade2cbe8dcdfdad4">
            <input
                type="radio"
                class="validation"
                name="attribute[52]"
                value="98"
                id="b6cc5db62235218dade2cbe8dcdfdad4"
                        />
            <span class="name">50 ML</span>
        </label>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to loop through the li and get the value of the input and change the the text of the class="name" within that li. If value = 97 then the text for that span should be 50 ML (RRP $69.00) for example.

We are using 3rd party stuff they render the page as they see fit. Need t be able to change it to what we need.

Thanks again for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that simply with this line of code:

```
$('.option input[value=97]').next('.name').text('50 ML (RRP $69.00)');
```

To make it easier to add more options, create an array to do the same:

```
var d = [
  {'value':'97','text':'50 ML (RRP $69.00)'},
  {'value':'[your value]','text':'[your text]'}
];

$(d).each(function() {
  $('.option input[value='+this.value+']').next('.name').text(this.text);
});
```

Comment: Nice one-liner!  That's a pretty slick way to do it if he's really only got that one switch to do, otherwise I think the other two answers might be more efficient.

Comment: I actually think this code is more efficient because it does not require putting `switch` or `if` statements within the `each()` function, removing the cruft.

Comment: I guess at second glance it does make sense.  I was assuming the OP had some sort of equation that he was going to be doing on those values in order to get the name.  Or that there was a huge database of values in the backend (this kind of looks like an ecommerce system, so that may be)...

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Here I would have that code produce the above array (possibly on the server side) so that it is in a simplified form and separates logic.

Comment: This is the one I used. Worked GREAT!! Thanks a stack mate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `$.each()` to go through them, and use `find()` to find the elements you need:

```
$('.option').each(function(i){
    var t = $(this).find('.name');
    switch ($(this).find('input').val()){
        case "97":
            t.text(" 50 ML (RRP $69.00)");
            break;
                case "98":
            t.text(" text for 98...");
            break;
    } 
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/XnAp3/

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple, using JQuery's each function.  Your code is gonna look like this:

```
$("li.option").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).children("input").val();

    //Put your logic here to decide what the span should say
    var name = "50 ML (RRP $69.00)";//Just putting this in for the example

    $(this).children("span.name").val(name);
});
```

That will loop through each of your li.options, grab the value of their child input element, then set their child span.name element to the value you want.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response appreciate it.